Async API - Bare minimum asyncapi.yaml for simple @RabbitListener
I have a hard time understanding AsyncApi format and I am trying to start from the basis in a really simple SpringBoot project with RabbitMQ
So let's suppose I just have, in my code:

A queue named "queue-one", which is referenced in a RabbitListener (see below)
A queue named "queue-two", which is declared in another RabbitListener (see below)
One of the @RabbitListener method is listening to / has a subscription to the exchange "exchange-one" along with routing-key "routing-key-one"

What would be the bare minimum asyncapi.yaml file corresponding to this java code?
Here is the Java code with the bean for the queue and the rabbitlistener:

@Bean
public org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue queueOne() {
    return new org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue("queue-one", false);
}

@RabbitListener(
        bindings = {@QueueBinding(
                exchange = @Exchange(
                        name = "exchange-one",
                        type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC
                ),
                value = @Queue(name = "queue-one"), / referenced queue
                key = "routing-key-one")
        })
public void receiveMessage1withReferencedQueue(@Payload Message1 message1) {
    log.info("Message {} received", message1);
}

@RabbitListener(queues = "queue-two")
public void receiveMessage1withDeclaredQueue(@Payload Message1 message1) {
    log.info("Message {} received", message1);
}


Questions:
A. Can you explicitly explained the mapping between:

RabbitMQ side:

exchange
routingKey
queue


AsyncApi side:

channels.<CHANNEL_NAME> how to 'create correct name based on 'RabbitMQ Side info'
channels.<CHANNEL_NAME>.bindings.amqp.queue and channels.<CHANNEL_NAME>.bindings.amqp.exchange . Also, Why the hell the is: key can be either queue or routingKey. I mean.. why 'routingKey'???
operations:* How should I take into account RabbitMQ ide info to create 'operations' in asyncapi.yaml ?
operations.<OPERATION_NAME>.bindings.amqp.cc is used as routingKey, right? (cfr AsyncApi documentation)



I would like to have a full and deep understanding on how to map information present in @RabbitListeners (and bean queues etc..) so I'll be able to create correct corresponding asyncapi.yaml files.
(And I know #springwolf does exists, but I first want to understand myself)
B. I tried to create a version of asyncapi.yaml, but I am pretty sure it's not correct rgarding my Java code. Any comments / guidance ?

asyncapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: AMQP Sample
  version: 1.0.0
defaultContentType: application/json
servers:
  amqp-server:
    host: amqp:5672
    protocol: amqp
channels:
  exchange-one:
    messages:
      Message1:
        $ref: '#/components/messages/Message1'
    bindings:
      amqp:
        is: routingKey
        exchange:
          name: exchange-one
          type: topic
          durable: true
          autoDelete: false
          vhost: /
        bindingVersion: 0.3.0
  queue-two:
    messages:
      Message1:
        $ref: '#/components/messages/Message1'
    bindings:
      amqp:
        is: queue
        queue:
          name: queue-two
          durable: true
          exclusive: false
          autoDelete: false
          vhost: /
        bindingVersion: 0.3.0
components:
  schemas:
    SpringRabbitListenerDefaultHeaders:
      type: object
      properties: {}
      examples:
        - {}
    Message1:
      type: object
      properties:
        value:
          type: string
          description: Value field
  messages:
    Message1:
      headers:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/SpringRabbitListenerDefaultHeaders'
      payload:
        schemaFormat: application/vnd.aai.asyncapi+json;version=3.0.0
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Message1'
      name: Message1
      title: Message1
      bindings:
        amqp:
          bindingVersion: 0.3.0
operations:
  exchange-one__with__routing-key-one__receive__Message1:
    action: receive
    channel:
      $ref: '#/channels/routing-key-one'
    bindings:
      amqp:
        expiration: 0
        cc:
          - routing-key-one
        bindingVersion: 0.3.0
    messages:
      - $ref: '#/channels/routing-key-one/messages/Message1'
  queue-two_receive_receiveMessage1withDeclaredQueue:
    action: receive
    channel:
      $ref: '#/channels/queue-two'
    bindings:
      amqp:
        expiration: 0
        cc:
          - queue-two
        bindingVersion: 0.3.0
    messages:
      - $ref: '#/channels/queue-two/messages/Message1'


Your question is pretty packed and hard to answer - can you trim it down? Also, #/channels/routing-key-one does not exist.

I have not used AMQP before, so take the AMQP specifics with a grain of salt.

What would be the bare minimum asyncapi.yaml file corresponding to this java code?

That depends on your use-case and what you want to use the AsyncAPI document for. I.e. what is the problem you are trying to solve, as AsyncAPI can solve multiple things.
Documenting infrastructure, simplifying implementation, documenting producers/consumers, or all the above?
The AsyncAPI document you added certainly aims for all of the above.

A. Can you explicitly explained the mapping between:

Think of it this way, AsyncAPI channels are the abstracted definition of a topic in RabbitMQ. There is no protocol specification information located there, because the same definitions should be easily ported to other protocols, so you are never locked into one. It is simply the roads in your infrastructure.
channels.<CHANNEL_NAME> is the id/name of the channel you wish to use. channels.<CHANNEL_NAME>.address is the RabbitMQ topic. Seems like the exchange.name is the same as channels.<CHANNEL_NAME>.address.
Is that the same with queue.name? I am not quite sure, I would raise the question on the GitHub repository.
I would probably for now keep a bit of duplicate entries or select one of them for the information.
...
channels:
  exchange-one:
    address: exchange-one
    messages:
      Message1:
        $ref: '#/components/messages/Message1'
    bindings:
      amqp:
        is: routingKey
        exchange:
          name: exchange-one
          type: topic
          durable: true
          autoDelete: false
        bindingVersion: 0.3.0


operations:* How should I take into account RabbitMQ ide info to create 'operations' in asyncapi.yaml ?

If channels are the roads, operations are the direction, is your application receiving/consuming information (cars driving into your city) or sending/producing/publishing something (cars driving out of your city).

channels.<CHANNEL_NAME>.bindings.amqp.queue and channels.<CHANNEL_NAME>.bindings.amqp.exchange . Also, Why the hell the is: key can be either queue or routingKey. I mean.. why 'routingKey'???

Good issue to raise in the repository. If it produces confusion please don't hesitate to propose a change in the repository.

operations.<OPERATION_NAME>.bindings.amqp.cc is used as routingKey, right? (cfr AsyncApi documentation)

Seems correct yes, but depends on how it's used further down the tooling line I guess.

B. I tried to create a version of asyncapi.yaml, but I am pretty sure it's not correct rgarding my Java code. Any comments / guidance ?

Here is how I would improve the AsyncAPI document:

No need to define messages under operations unless the channel has defined multiple messages where you want to whitelist only a small section of them.
By default schemaFormat is application/vnd.aai.asyncapi+json;version=3.0.0, so you can simply reference the schema directly.

asyncapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: AMQP Sample
  version: 1.0.0
defaultContentType: application/json
servers:
  amqp-server:
    host: amqp:5672
    protocol: amqp
channels:
  exchange-one:
    address: exchange-one
    messages:
      Message1:
        $ref: '#/components/messages/Message1'
    bindings:
      amqp:
        is: routingKey
        exchange:
          name: exchange-one
          type: topic
          durable: true
          autoDelete: false
        bindingVersion: 0.3.0
  queue-two:
    address: queue-two
    messages:
      Message1:
        $ref: '#/components/messages/Message1'
    bindings:
      amqp:
        is: queue
        queue: 
          name: queue-two
          durable: true
          exclusive: false
          autoDelete: false
        bindingVersion: 0.3.0
operations:
  exchange-one__with__routing-key-one__receive__Message1:
    action: receive
    channel:
      $ref: '#/channels/exchange-one'
    bindings:
      amqp:
        cc:
          - routing-key-one
        bindingVersion: 0.3.0
  queue-two_receive_receiveMessage1withDeclaredQueue:
    action: receive
    channel:
      $ref: '#/channels/queue-two'
    bindings:
      amqp:
        cc:
          - queue-two
        bindingVersion: 0.3.0

components:
  schemas:
    SpringRabbitListenerDefaultHeaders:
      type: object
      properties: {}
      examples:
        - {}
    Message1:
      type: object
      properties:
        value:
          type: string
          description: Value field
  messages:
    Message1:
      headers:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/SpringRabbitListenerDefaultHeaders'
      payload:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Message1'
      name: Message1
      title: Message1

Hope some of this helped clarify some things. Remember the bindings are still early stages, jumping in to mature them is the best way forward! Cause they do seem a bit weird.

Thanks @jonaslagoni I'll try to go further in the understanding of this. If asyncapi/bindings team could provide a simple example about this, that would be great.

The best way would be to create an issue in the bindings repository and then reach out on the AsyncAPI Slack to notify people about the question

I was wondering.. should I also have a queue-one channel? or not ? Because I have a Queue("queue-one"..) bean in my code, so "queue-one" is created on RabbitMQ server, but it's not mentioned in the asyncapi.yaml file here.. So I guess I am missing something...
